# Chops of pork or pork chops?

Tags: word-order, phrases, attributive-nouns

What is the correct way to say it? I have heard "chops of pork" is incorrect, but I do not understand why? What is the rule to follow?

Comment: Well, it should be the same reason why people say "_Chicken Drumstick_" and not "_drumsticks of chicken_".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pork chop** actually has its own entry in [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pork_chop) and in [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pork-chop), as well as in the OED (where the first citation, from the 1750s, is hyphenated - as are several of the more recent occurrences).

So "pork chop" is a very well established compound noun.

Of course, "chop" is also in the dictionaries, and one of its definitions is "a thick slice of meat, especially pork or lamb, adjacent to and often including a rib" ([Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/chop)).  Thus, it would be grammatically correct to refer to "chops of pork"... but (in most contexts, at least) it wouldn't be idiomatic.

You just have to learn how native speakers refer to something.  "A chicken leg" and "a leg of chicken" are both acceptable, but "a chop of pork" sounds weird. However, there may be other phrases where the "of" version is the usual one.  It is usually not easy to find a consistent logic behind it.